# Transitioning to vim. Having issues with indentation

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am recovering from a surgery, thusly, I am transitioning to VIM.  As I starting point, I've opted to use the vim-sensible plugin as the foundation of my configuration.  Additionally, I've installed the 'vim-rails' and 'vim-ruby' plugins.  These are all loaded via Pathogen.

For whatever reason, the plugins are not adjusting indentation settings in accord with filetype.  Tabs seem locked to 9 columns.  I am able to set them manually, but obviously this is not ideal.

Here is my .vimrc.  As you can see, it is very basic.

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your `vimrc` file. For starters make sure you have the following line in your `~/.vimrc` file: `filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: Maybe you're expecting the wrong thing. As someone alluded to, pressing "tab" will *manually* increase the indent by "shiftwidth" spaces. That has nothing to do with the filetype-based indent settings. The filetype-based indent settings affect *automatic* indentation, only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim provides the following buffer local options for managing indention: `'softtabstop'`, `'shiftwidth'`, `'tabstop'`, and `'expandtab'`. The idea is to set these options for a specific filetype, e.g. `ruby` either by using an `autocommand` or using the after ftplugin directory (my preference).

#### After directory approach

Add the following to your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim` file:

```
setlocal softtabstop=2
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal tabstop=2
```

#### Autocommand approach

Add the following to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
augroup MyIndentSettings
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType ruby setlocal softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
augroup END
```

#### Learn more

As you are just starting to vim it is best to learn how to query these options so you can track down future bugs. Querying an option is as simple as `:verbose set {option}?`, e.g. `:verbose set expandtab?`.

You may also be interested in Tim Pope's [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) which heuristically sets indent settings.

For more help see:

```
:h :set
:h 'softtabstop'
:h 'shiftwidth'
:h 'tabstop'
:h 'expandtab'
:h after-directory
```

Comment: Thanks... vim-sleuth delivers the expected behavior.

Comment: @mattmarcello if this answers your question you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark <---

Answer (score 1):

In my vimrc I have the following:

```
set autoindent
set expandtabs
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
```

Actually I just have

```
set ai et sw=4 ts=4
```

You can change the specific settings using `FileType` or `BufEnter`:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.py ai et sw=4 ts=4
```

Comment: You should not add buffer local settings to your `~/.vimrc` file as ftplugin's get sourced afterwards. Even if this did work it makes little sense to have these settings for all filetypes, e.g. `set expandtab` and Makefile's do not mix. You are missing the `set`/`setlocal` in your `autocmd`. You may want to use an [`augroup` and `autocmd!` pattern](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html) to guard your auto command from being resourced.

Comment: Hm. That's weird. I've definitely got expandtab, but I can edit makefiles without problem. Of course now that I think about it, it's probably because I rely on the autoindent and don't hit tab myself.

Comment: No, it is because ftplugins are sourced after your vimrc when editing a file. Edit a makefile (or do `:set ft=make`) then run `:verbose set expandtab?` to see where your settings are coming from. The setting will be coming from `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugins/`. Now go open up some other files and do the verbose set command again to see where they are coming from. I imagine you will not fine any coming from your vimrc unless they are apart of an autocmd.

Comment: Sure enough. Learned something new!