# Tabs for indentation in python files in vim

Tags: python, vim, tabs

I'm trying to get vim to indent using tabs for python files. I don't want a discussion about the merits of tabs vs spaces, I just want tabs. In my vimrc, I not only have

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop
```

but I also have some python specific settings:

```
augroup python_files
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python setlocal noexpandtab
    autocmd FileType Python set tabstop=4
    autocmd FileType Python set shiftwidth=4
augroup END
```

This seems like it should correctly set my indentation settings in python files but when I open one, it shows literal tabs as 8 characters wide and the TAB key inserts 4 spaces. Is there something else that I could be doing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out. In my `augroup`, I was using a capital "P" in Python, when it should be lowercase. This following works perfectly:

```
augroup python_files
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python setlocal noexpandtab
    autocmd FileType python set tabstop=4
    autocmd FileType python set shiftwidth=4
augroup END
```

Comment: Glad you got this worked out. You may want to consider putting these settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. I find using the after directory simpler and easier to maintain. Here is a nice post about it: [Transitioning to vim. Having issues with indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27804353/438329)

Comment: I actually did that before trying the `augroup`, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Use `setlocal` instead of `set`.