# Python-mode in Vim not autoindenting on newline

Tags: python, vim

I have the python-mode vim plugin installed, and it checks syntax correctly, but it does not automatically indent code when I start a new line.

I'm not sure what might be preventing this, so here's my vimrc.

.vimrc:

```
"" Pathogen settings
filetype off
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
filetype plugin on

set nocompatible

" Change leader
let mapleader = ","

" Set color scheme
colorscheme badwolf

" Code settings
syntax on
set textwidth=100
set colorcolumn=100
set tabstop=8
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set expandtab
set nowrap
set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0

set relativenumber
set number
set ruler

" Make it so jk returns to normal mode
inoremap jk <esc>

" Easy editing/sourcing of vimrc
nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>

" Useful shortcuts
nnoremap <leader>w :w<cr>
nnoremap <leader>q :q<cr>
nnoremap <leader><space> bi<space><esc>ea<space><esc>

" Plugin shortcuts
nnoremap <c-n> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>k
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l
nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>h

nnoremap <leader>l :TagbarToggle<cr>
nnoremap <leader>td <Plug>TaskList
nnoremap <leader>g :GundoToggle<cr>


" Vimscript file settings ---------- {{{
augroup filetype_vim
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType vim setlocal foldmethod=marker
augroup END
" }}}

" Python file settings ---------- {{{
augroup filetype_python
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType python setlocal foldmethod=indent
  autocmd FileType python set foldlevel=99
" }}}
```

Plugins I have installed:

```
ack        git        minibufexpl.vim  snipmate  tagbar
command-t  gundo      nerdtree         supertab  tasklist
fugitive   makegreen  python-mode      surround  vim-airline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `filetype plugin on` to `filetype indent plugin on`

Comment: This was the solution, I had that at one point and removed it for other file types. Thanks!

Comment: You also want to remove all you indent settings from your `~/.vimrc` file as they are buffer local settings. Related posts: [Vim settings constantly getting reset](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25898409/438329)  and [Transitioning to vim. Having issues with indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27804353/438329)